# Contenido invalido esquema XML

Tags: xml

Buenas, estoy realizando el esquema de mi archivo XML, y a la hora de validar me sale este error en el validador, a ver si me podéis echar una mano para resolverlo y comprender que pasa. Gracias.

Este es el error:

> Errors in file xml-schema: 
>       21: 19  s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_sucursalpedidos' is invalid. Element 'sequence' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

Este mi archivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<pedidos    
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Ejercicio4_2.xsd">
    <sucursal codigo="X5486954">        

        <direccion departamento="exposicion"> C/Confin 12</direccion>       
        <direccion departamento="xestion"> C/Catorse 40</direccion>     
        <nombre_empleado>Antonio Bouzada Sastre</nombre_empleado>
        <fecha>10/03/2017</fecha>
        <observaciones>Entregar en horario de oficina.</observaciones>
        <prazo_revision>15</prazo_revision>
        <articulo codigo="ABS-768">
            <unidades>150</unidades>
            <precio>550</precio>
        </articulo>             

        <articulo codigo="ABS-769">
            <unidades>20</unidades>
            <precio>800</precio>
            <observaciones_articulo>Embalar individualmente.</observaciones_articulo>       
        </articulo>             
    </sucursal>     

    <sucursal codigo="L7683421">        
        <direccion departamento="ambas"> C/Sineiro 12</direccion>       
        <nombre_empleado>Alfredo Rojo Casal</nombre_empleado>
        <fecha>05/03/2017</fecha>
        <observaciones>Urgente</observaciones>
        <prazo_revision>10</prazo_revision>
        <articulo codigo="ARC-008">
            <unidades>100</unidades>
            <precio>90</precio>
            <observaciones_articulo>Embalar en paquetes de 10.</observaciones_articulo>     
        </articulo>         
    </sucursal>
</pedidos>
```

Y este mi esquema XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="Es-es">
        Tarefa Unidad 04 Linguaxes de Marcas "Pedidos empresa Distanza S.A."
        <fecha>2017-03-13</fecha>
        <autor>Ivan Vieites Lores</autor>       
    </xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>


<xsd:element name="pedidos">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="sucursal" maxOccurs="unbounded" >                
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:attribute name="codigo" type="codigo" use="required"/>

                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="direccion" type="xsd:string" >
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:attribute name="departamento" type="departamento" use="required"/>
                        </xsd:complexType>                      
                    </xsd:element>                  
                    <xsd:element name="nombre_empleado" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="fecha" type="xsd:date" />
                    <xsd:element name="observaciones" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xsd:element name="prazo_revision" type="xsd:integer"/>                 
                    <xsd:element name="articulo" minOcurss="1" maxOcurss="unbounded">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:attribute name="codigo" type="art_codigo" use="required"/>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="unidades" type="xsd:integer"/>
                                <xsd:element name="precio" type="xsd:integer"/>
                                <xsd:element name="observaciones_articulo" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>                  
                    </xsd:element>              
                </xsd:sequence>         
                </xsd:complexType>  
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>  
</xsd:element>



 <xsd:simpleType name="codigo" >
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:pattern value="[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9]){7}" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

 <xsd:simpleType name="departamento" >
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="exposicion"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="xestion"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="ambas"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

 <xsd:simpleType name="art_codigo" >
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:pattern value="[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{3}" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

te dejo una estructura espero te funcione

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsd:element name="orden" type="orden"/>
 <xsd:element name="comentario" type="xsd:string"/>

 <xsd:complexType name="tipoorden">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="forma" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="pago" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="comentario" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="producto"  type="type="xsd:string""/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="fecha" type="xsd:date"/>
 </xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:complexType name="direccion">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="nombre" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="calle" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="ciudad" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="numero" type="xsd:decimal"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:complexType name="informacion">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="info">
    <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="producto" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="cantidad" type="xsd:integer" />
      <xsd:element name="precio" type="xsd:decimal"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```